# Documentation for CGS Methods (Core Graphics Services)

Tags: ios, macos, core-graphics

Where can I find the documentation for Core Graphics Services method specifically these methods: CGSGetWindowBounds and CGSNewRegionWithData. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is none. Those functions are private and undocumented. If you Google their names, you'll find some places people have written about them, but Apple doesn't mean for you to be using them in the first place.

Comment: So I am not allowed to use them if I want my app to be in App Store?